# Unity Android Il2CPP Build Not playing animation after loading Asset bundle

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mono, il2cpp

I run assetbundle in Mono Build animation is working properly(it's working fine in editor also) when I create IL2CPP build then load assetbundle animation is not woking.

Unity version : 2020.3.3f1

Is anyone face this issue before if so then please provide solution

Answer (score 0):

After wasting about a week was able to know why this problem is occurring.

steps to reproduce this scenario

1. Create Scene 1 and Don't use any animation by the animator component. Load next scene is called scene 2. Like below
   [image]
2. On scene 2 load Assetbundle which contained animation (Here you'll notice that Animation is not playing)

How do I fix it?

1. In scene 1, I've added one small animation

[image]

2. Now when I load asset bundle on scene 2 animation play as per expectation

Somehow I realized that unity is not initialing animation component by default and if we assign animator controller then only it's get  initialized.

That's why when we load asset bundle in first case it was not playing an animation.
But in case 2 Was able to play animation default.